# iterate over a nested dataframe and print kables in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I have a dataframe with nested datraframes for every year. I'm trying to print each nested dataframe in the result column as a kable using kableExtra in RMarkdown.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
MWU_Results
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    YEAR    data.oratios data.kfmaratios result           
   <dbl> <list<df[,16]>> <list<df[,16]>> <list>           
 1  2008        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 2  2009        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 3  2010        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 4  2011        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 5  2012        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 6  2013        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 7  2014        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 8  2015        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 9  2016        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
10  2017        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
```

What is the best way of doing this?

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(devtools)
    library(inspectdf)
    library(readr)
    library(broom)
    library(knitr)
    library(readxl)
    library(skimr)
    library(kableExtra)

kable(purrr::map2(MWU_Results$result, MWU_Results$YEAR)) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

I've included sample data for the problem I'm trying to solve. The KFMARatios sample is rather large so I only have data for 2008.

**Sample data:**

ORATIOS:

```
structure(list(YEAR = c(2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017), FARM = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I"), 
    `CURRENT RATIO` = c(0.568022785746452, 0.329854720020037, 
    0.832073159580644, 0.643108790851367, 25.1454874121908, 14.5975395062397, 
    5.12537888750377, 5.20160770260219, 7.64257374037806, 2.1580962424325, 
    1.31703632160198, 0.125166573684741, 0.0680923398879462, 
    0.100452384108057, 0.0998706900125819, 0.0907309088049343, 
    0.521537398114045, 0.773433351511582, 0.174099653043861, 
    0.0804425861373205), `WORKING CAPITAL TO GROSS FARMING INCOME` = c(-0.132573843177753, 
    -0.419436996986394, -0.031444400685141, -0.114022796397208, 
    1.22962822585944, 0.397841184148093, 0.239623650110705, 0.295681875030473, 
    0.502930206605254, 0.41862926754376, 0.0513905118422565, 
    -0.406448322702947, -0.343476652794216, -0.366684678854441, 
    -0.27321810774102, -0.306827980132377, -0.173010159020099, 
    -0.140768598200492, -0.367184395657858, -0.888263538055031
    ), `DEBT TO TOTAL ASSET RATIO` = c(0.0846892634197993, 0.102127561711337, 
    0.0750728145035032, 0.0797349374471145, 0.0122514875519798, 
    0.0162967044282012, 0.0165670856047258, 0.0188732833402721, 
    0.0150968780472965, 0.0275252089477482, 0.1123291162633, 
    0.151496340475165, 0.0960615511639704, 0.0985641068765839, 
    0.119816717131179, 0.121164074695269, 0.0970056997272376, 
    0.139114211255347, 0.0686657852466466, 0.17098484263781), 
    `DEBT TO FARM ASSET RATIO` = c(0.0935832744841849, 0.114259598684054, 
    0.0824723632268821, 0.08365143337564, 0.0129689938858425, 
    0.0191316764222117, 0.0216751963945452, 0.0225358439285237, 
    0.0167830935834987, 0.030821228954403, 0.140068283663094, 
    0.203393535891141, 0.133942894025292, 0.137887444914688, 
    0.17818477721901, 0.182143899668642, 0.141540075268137, 0.212926916788055, 
    0.0962721755129152, 0.172706971368876), `EQUITY TO ASSET RATIO` = c(0.915310736580201, 
    0.897872438288663, 0.924927185496497, 0.920265062552885, 
    0.98774851244802, 0.983703295571799, 0.983432914395274, 0.981126716659728, 
    0.984903121952704, 0.972474791052252, 0.8876708837367, 0.848503659524835, 
    0.90393844883603, 0.901435893123416, 0.880183282868821, 0.878835925304732, 
    0.902994300272762, 0.860885788744653, 0.931334214753353, 
    0.82901515736219), `DEBT TO EQUITY RATIO` = c(0.0925251502415636, 
    0.113743954437438, 0.0811661887343104, 0.0866434472975902, 
    0.0124034482437396, 0.0165666868267717, 0.0168461776723358, 
    0.0192363361631072, 0.0153282873318188, 0.0283042904566863, 
    0.126543652970169, 0.178545300040313, 0.106270013503315, 
    0.109341227289126, 0.13612700838927, 0.137868823072129, 0.107426702137473, 
    0.161594270778014, 0.0737284040024573, 0.206250562633691), 
    `RETURN ON FARM ASSETS` = c(0.0170145283510924, -0.00522377886147693, 
    0.0237250420249203, 0.00257743472229431, 0.0213365859181817, 
    0.0244609737360482, 0.0279373354305636, 0.0167869242322396, 
    0.0572363957452595, -0.00273821783417637, 0.0325678749005671, 
    -0.0532931806283685, 0.024215521265722, -0.0178636730481072, 
    0.0189254399688753, 0.00211416100547258, -0.00938005681041073, 
    0.0501921695586829, 0.0215269026374393, -0.0366154070757298
    ), `RETURN ON ASSETS` = c(0.0566608458884666, 0.0239054711694685, 
    0.0264084815850861, 0.00576204495548541, 0.179667366138176, 
    0.0246773695339781, 0.0246552659101915, 0.020526505137709, 
    0.0551370549195115, -5.05665725060606e-05, 0.0449112877923212, 
    -0.0284073208306705, 0.0249952584312144, -0.00283565027536605, 
    0.0360687362998932, 0.0080927754538142, -0.00331579015236834, 
    0.0457634829675583, 0.0229640648122328, -0.023016837706958
    ), `RETURN ON EQUITY` = c(0.0168221490501512, -0.00520020437367425, 
    0.023349291367177, 0.00266962346623839, 0.0204061503508897, 
    0.0211814836515069, 0.0217131742563291, 0.0143291246913213, 
    0.0522749822883451, -0.002514608130223, 0.0294232052511338, 
    -0.0467824450944562, 0.0192125442012039, -0.0141654371518756, 
    0.0144583817182496, 0.00160025611694793, -0.00711931632857772, 
    0.0380917883044123, 0.0164860113123938, -0.0437269454184399
    ), `FARM OPERATING PROFIT MARGIN RATIO` = c(0.113108456739495, 
    -0.0455472105804567, 0.199838203998892, 0.0234275923606582, 
    0.158472105656006, 0.183710042172317, 0.190582976791897, 
    0.124927655425634, 0.45847835351018, -0.0422031337055503, 
    0.122121670323183, -0.243017854350921, 0.11277681710057, 
    -0.0790679940692684, 0.076084143213901, 0.00890894198839937, 
    -0.0450368591167229, 0.204577659697265, 0.13619384495868, 
    -0.358538500350435), `ASSET TURNOVER RATIO` = c(0.0153974936379558, 
    -0.00466912018059027, 0.0215963943475807, 0.00245676120615052, 
    0.0201561446538819, 0.0208362952730876, 0.0213534502396742, 
    0.0140586870610039, 0.0514857932558134, -0.00244539301601691, 
    0.0261181226076402, -0.0396950758641658, 0.0173669574034299, 
    -0.0127692334904846, 0.0127260258857395, 0.00140636256526249, 
    -0.00642870206654449, 0.0327926792191383, 0.0153539864000432, 
    -0.0362503005370359), `OPERATING EXPENSE RATIO` = c(0.671535228245263, 
    0.773166498456329, 0.607985458258, 0.724432447012029, 0.67336000606662, 
    0.64796797949329, 0.589032574693052, 0.74988495257417, 0.461775664398759, 
    0.862141471389961, 0.672863504023624, 0.980455882037588, 
    0.669661413731221, 0.86690216270866, 0.670033358895902, 0.737005445439968, 
    0.783494244501376, 0.649760819934915, 0.706382908455109, 
    1.134948535946), `DEPRECIATION EXPENSE RATIO` = c(0.12660532789432, 
    0.132732814909818, 0.103826844188336, 0.144629676126728, 
    0.140059287930065, 0.157478624539652, 0.141620283491016, 
    0.0919194664659044, 0.0583370508964949, 0.133579109920113, 
    0.150646135557582, 0.183514628711121, 0.146236932328879, 
    0.16125312788589, 0.191531747619893, 0.197293862401247, 0.193527787561396, 
    0.0913809290148264, 0.0946887014018637, 0.145522583536315
    ), `INTEREST EXPENSE RATIO` = c(0.0887509871209225, 0.139647897214309, 
    0.0883494935547731, 0.107510284500585, 0.028108600347309, 
    0.0108433537947408, 0.0787641650240354, 0.0332679255342914, 
    0.0214089311945663, 0.0464825523954769, 0.0543686900956105, 
    0.0790473436022124, 0.0713248368393299, 0.0509127034747178, 
    0.0623507502703033, 0.0567917501703862, 0.068014827053951, 
    0.0542805913529945, 0.0627345451843474, 0.0780673808681226
    ), `NET FARM INCOME RATIO` = c(0.113108456739495, -0.0455472105804567, 
    0.199838203998892, 0.0234275923606582, 0.158472105656006, 
    0.183710042172317, 0.190582976791897, 0.124927655425634, 
    0.45847835351018, -0.0422031337055503, 0.122121670323183, 
    -0.243017854350921, 0.11277681710057, -0.0790679940692684, 
    0.076084143213901, 0.00890894198839937, -0.0450368591167229, 
    0.204577659697265, 0.13619384495868, -0.358538500350435)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

KFMARATIOS:

```
 structure(list(YEAR = c(2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
    2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
    2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
    2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008
    ), FARM = c(11407100, 11484600, 11485100, 11495100, 11801800, 
    11806400, 11820000, 11885400, 11886000, 11897200, 11897300, 12004500, 
    12004501, 12303001, 12340101, 12398300, 13050001, 13700201, 13705601, 
    14089100, 14110900, 14130000, 14130002, 14184100, 14192300, 14330302, 
    14388200, 14783200, 14786200, 15094200, 15096200, 15584200, 15586100, 
    15682100, 15683100, 15689100, 16507002, 16580000, 16598200, 16601300
    ), `CURRENT RATIO` = c(-3, 0, 4.57, 15.94, 2.22, 0, 368.69, 1.86, 
    9.1, 3.45, 2, 0, 1.58, 6.26, 1.97, 1.54, 0, 3.39, 313.09, 5.59, 
    5.4, 0, 3.6, 5.78, 3.18, 207.1, 2.36, 28.31, 3.4, 3.68, 0.37, 
    3.5, 5.6, 13.64, 7.05, 0, 2.23, 0.89, 4.4, 1.11), `WORKING CAPITAL TO GROSS FARMING INCOME` = c(0.783990044655886, 
    0.939342207539837, 0.468883358203084, 0.53708199556795, 0.429230789973027, 
    0.856616290636639, 0.46085746623408, 0.019246546772549, 1.04338230212655, 
    0.318770448161572, 0.398058372857175, 0.506978780306214, 0.263816960947357, 
    0.4960655740923, 0.101962576323424, 0.220623464476751, 1.12676140487953, 
    0.533690322762107, 0.685276501922026, 0.703540899065169, 0.660869855557338, 
    0.71777803486123, 0.319578323479609, 0.722736340214157, 0.286630301648443, 
    0.818610240507597, 0.184477489966846, 0.78148168000963, 0.357891811040315, 
    0.289159422203956, -0.125641128630768, 0.392321597654173, 0.561996673317676, 
    0.353452531903466, 0.683345718597063, 0.804567295215173, 0.307398272114796, 
    -0.375449779668313, 0.186702574682293, -0.55737251721071), `DEBT TO TOTAL ASSET RATIO` = c(0.02, 
    0.07, 0.27, 0.37, 0.36, 0, 0.07, 0.37, 0.05, 0.33, 0.42, 0.08, 
    0.24, 0.34, 0.36, 0.51, 0.01, 0.11, 0.1, 0.07, 0.08, 0.01, 0.32, 
    0.14, 0.4, 0.52, 0.39, 0.06, 0.21, 0.32, 0.43, 0.52, 0.29, 0.12, 
    0.17, 0.1, 0.15, 0.87, 0.12, 0.69), `DEBT TO FARM ASSET RATIO` = c(0.0210960466847519, 
    0.0662443993261916, 0.270051570315789, 0.373240578143398, 0.359031265562519, 
    0, 0.0678176279710153, 0.369000587598404, 0.04831743727994, 0.33065743433488, 
    0.41680939549244, 0.0851067276205844, 0.245359588845858, 0.337912727823456, 
    0.356607488633417, 0.508663012923272, 0.0126098421632802, 0.10665178903834, 
    0.105106247793806, 0.0698908293989529, 0.0818483764283224, 0.00750932570017385, 
    0.319501072718455, 0.136757510256717, 0.400840648545665, 0.516753083750126, 
    0.389587948103612, 0.0577299469460252, 0.206521419569117, 0.315261383020663, 
    0.43256943562472, 0.520491208048298, 0.290288373137576, 0.120229338185664, 
    0.173192986515349, 0.104536048245734, 0.151997186500475, 0.868552025800098, 
    0.123958600776313, 0.692195974317741), `EQUITY TO ASSET RATIO` = c(0.98536882817945, 
    0.944215770167283, 0.736537746555766, 0.729860554651407, 0.642228778874089, 
    1, 0.94228148558872, 0.630999412401596, 0.95168256272006, 0.66934256566512, 
    0.592693562701164, 0.914893272379416, 0.813956784138156, 0.688995447780108, 
    0.725420084109645, 0.545241148972386, 0.988536562104007, 0.900124825958172, 
    0.90344241855196, 0.930936390469265, 0.92060316189968, 0.992490674299826, 
    0.758518009863028, 0.881474617998699, 0.600468426703118, 0.553595877267449, 
    0.667405715763261, 0.942270053053975, 0.842757601135073, 0.708413078986436, 
    0.56743056437528, 0.533041296742996, 0.743304732269968, 0.88511363093375, 
    0.831970255984885, 0.904591907651469, 0.876296809602567, 0.131447974199902, 
    0.890119750534961, 0.307804025682259), `DEBT TO EQUITY RATIO` = c(0.02, 
    0.07, 0.37, 0.6, 0.56, 0, 0.07, 0.58, 0.05, 0.49, 0.72, 0.09, 
    0.32, 0.51, 0.55, 1.04, 0.01, 0.12, 0.12, 0.08, 0.09, 0.01, 0.47, 
    0.16, 0.67, 1.07, 0.64, 0.06, 0.26, 0.46, 0.76, 1.08, 0.41, 0.14, 
    0.21, 0.12, 0.18, 6.61, 0.14, 2.25), `RETURN ON FARM ASSETS` = c(0.374484329540697, 
    0.0498819566035984, 0.181954755022922, 0.193161758267218, 0.0473627311001023, 
    0.327305563029612, 0.603037930741254, -0.0156737997438482, 0.10397858597475, 
    0.10789191406389, 0.180771277730155, 0.150007797084, 0.174196776278552, 
    0.120122100767257, 0.298096858936563, 0.0517125227815447, 0.111597414809764, 
    0.185024421154621, 0.239979711875599, 0.0808784377916965, 0.201436668181771, 
    0.135024051506645, 0.251851638310215, 0.103285147847268, 0.14207589091784, 
    0.247675592658745, 0.100067311604358, 0.308209326567443, 0.154555623216289, 
    0.174464204907127, 0.00457531564104158, 0.098141499884622, 0.251116584438097, 
    0.153198476415449, 0.183688952743912, 0.0838032420725189, 0.169288085631256, 
    0.0279120898963428, 0.147329195543669, 0.034801030826966), `RETURN ON ASSETS` = c(0.260063898261748, 
    0.0581159003954688, 0.186586004612603, 0.144217266907855, 0.0471965084015535, 
    0.203276288956977, 0.522691591931166, -0.0156737997438482, 0.104160943214225, 
    0.110451790466256, 0.178360409188664, 0.150089138729099, 0.134029707705111, 
    0.120565772385725, 0.229528019076799, 0.0697390623585822, 0.10198296142804, 
    0.192570247620748, 0.245119340816501, 0.115758491252085, 0.195889106965538, 
    0.138158444053898, 0.231674956423303, 0.0966027636728098, 0.141766843553559, 
    0.215113054221126, 0.135495862386357, 0.314351616201071, 0.133076845003381, 
    0.168262801476855, 0.00457531564104158, 0.0986664889666124, 0.242490501823923, 
    0.152124266735103, 0.201716489655936, 0.0786665142081486, 0.162659186669921, 
    0.0279454048764536, 0.134992616527726, 0.034801030826966), `RETURN ON EQUITY` = c(0.263580248064511, 
    0.0444871419402714, 0.241012793134955, 0.191549228659637, 0.0734886226747657, 
    0.186089113513671, 0.544673844576945, -0.0248396423765173, 0.109257634896201, 
    0.161190875342999, 0.298045789765326, 0.163962072531003, 0.162274234481587, 
    0.160460729376603, 0.31640703656353, 0.0847926292565323, 0.102628180483108, 
    0.192493344561337, 0.244023637469295, 0.0858503015508329, 0.212255623707772, 
    0.13604566269794, 0.250952374400512, 0.101551944180348, 0.235835707060263, 
    0.386487527831846, 0.128000474163853, 0.327092350614891, 0.139632557156543, 
    0.227780755169442, 0.0080632167674627, 0.165179790324242, 0.298742298993181, 
    0.165391606109475, 0.214205739228479, 0.084552656304169, 0.157224605882577, 
    0.212343248849882, 0.146717984157146, 0.113062299136044), `FARM OPERATING PROFIT MARGIN RATIO` = c(0.55, 
    0.18, 0.29, 0.33, 0.12, 0.46, 0.24, -0.1, 0.14, 0.23, 0.2, 0.22, 
    0.44, 0.25, 0.33, 0.13, 0.36, 0.44, 0.33, 0.05, 0.32, 0.16, 0.52, 
    0.3, 0.24, 0.35, 0.2, 0.32, 0.38, 0.29, 0.02, 0.24, 0.36, 0.25, 
    0.4, 0.18, 0.32, -0.01, 0.08, -0.01), `ASSET TURNOVER RATIO` = c(0.64, 
    0.2, 0.55, 0.58, 0.29, 0.64, 1.88, 0.39, 0.31, 0.34, 0.72, 0.58, 
    0.38, 0.41, 0.96, 0.38, 0.26, 0.4, 0.62, 0.41, 0.55, 0.67, 0.53, 
    0.29, 0.51, 0.86, 0.38, 0.94, 0.4, 0.54, 0.65, 0.49, 0.7, 0.49, 
    0.41, 0.3, 0.47, 0.62, 0.87, 0.79), `OPERATING EXPENSE RATIO` = c(0.29, 
    0.57, 0.61, 0.52, 0.69, 0.48, 0.57, 0.89, 0.64, 0.57, 0.72, 0.62, 
    0.45, 0.55, 0.52, 0.69, 0.49, 0.43, 0.5, 0.75, 0.53, 0.69, 0.38, 
    0.54, 0.6, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56, 0.5, 0.57, 0.87, 0.61, 0.54, 0.63, 
    0.44, 0.61, 0.56, 0.82, 0.77, 0.83), `DEPRECIATION EXPENSE RATIO` = c(0.08, 
    0.16, 0.01, 0.05, 0.07, 0.02, 0.03, 0.09, 0.02, 0.06, 0.03, 0.1, 
    0.04, 0.08, 0.06, 0.1, 0.06, 0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.08, 0.09, 0.04, 
    0.06, 0.05, 0.01, 0.11, 0.05, 0.04, 0.06, 0.05, 0.08, 0.04, 0.03, 
    0.06, 0.08, 0.01, 0.1, 0.05, 0.04), `INTEREST EXPENSE RATIO` = c(0.01, 
    0, 0.03, 0.07, 0.08, 0, 0, 0.06, 0, 0.02, 0.04, 0.01, 0.02, 0.06, 
    0.03, 0.06, 0, 0, 0.03, 0.01, 0.02, 0, 0.06, 0.01, 0.05, 0, 0.07, 
    0, 0.04, 0.01, 0.08, 0.1, 0.04, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.04, 0.04, 
    0.01, 0.09), `NET FARM INCOME RATIO` = c(0.62, 0.27, 0.35, 0.36, 
    0.16, 0.5, 0.39, -0.04, 0.34, 0.35, 0.22, 0.28, 0.49, 0.31, 0.39, 
    0.15, 0.45, 0.51, 0.44, 0.2, 0.37, 0.21, 0.52, 0.39, 0.29, 0.45, 
    0.27, 0.39, 0.43, 0.36, 0.01, 0.21, 0.37, 0.32, 0.47, 0.28, 0.38, 
    0.05, 0.17, 0.05)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -40L))
```

Comment: Please make this reproducible and include a sample of data using `dput(SAMPLE_OF_DATA)`. Your question shows how your data prints, but we don't know anything about the list-columns there aside from their dimensions. That makes answering in a useful way much harder.  Also, what does "it doesn't work" mean specifically? Did you get an error, or was the result different from expectations?

Comment: I've included the sample data.